# Cómo mostrar en pantalla propiedades de imágenes

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que se muestre automáticamente en la página los siguientes valores:

pixeles X pixeles de la imagen, tamaño en KB de la imagen y nombre de archivo de la imagen.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
<p>AQUÍ VAN LAS PROPIEDADES DE LA IMAGEN DE ABAJO</p>
<div id='first_image'>
<img src='New folder/01.jpg'>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Es básicamente para no tener que escribirlo manualmente si pongo 100 imágenes, que con JavaScript/CSS/HTML se escriba automáticamente de cada imagen.
Supongo que tengo usar elementos como getAttribute, pero luego ¿cómo lo pongo en pantalla?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El ancho y el alto de las imágenes puedes obtenerlos a través de las propiedades `naturalWidth` y `naturalHeight` del objeto `Image`.

Para obtener el tamaño en Kb es más complicado. Podrías utilizar la api Fetch ([Utilizando Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch). Los navegadores modernos ya la soportan aunque, eso sí, no te funcionará con Internet Explorer. (Hay algún polyfill disponible si necesitas soportar navegadores antiguos).

```js
var imagenes = [
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Minions_characters.png',
  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuOhy0zzWM5yPH0J9c4U-dVAQWYtVmhx6-4mKqA9E4tTIwALYQmg',
  'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91j4RxZvJxL._SL1500_.jpg',
  'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41HPFwV%2BdYL._SY355_.jpg',
  'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1571/3609/files/minion_hey.jpg?15458489482179744754',
  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbgTeUpNVMzF14DCjI8ykJrIPaGELzWGFSn3lGOiPYAwJ8DfhqTQ',
  'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6379795.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Minion.jpg'
];

function cargarImagen(){
  // Si no hay más imagenes salimos
  if (!imagenes.length) return;
  
  // Cogemos imagen a cargar
  var ruta = imagenes.pop();
  var imagen = new Image();
  // Una vez cargada se procesará
  imagen.addEventListener('load', imagenCargada);
  // Cargamos la ruta en la imagen
  imagen.src = ruta;
}

function imagenCargada(e){
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  // Coger las propiedades
  // El nombre lo extraemos de la ruta (entre el último / y el primer ?)
  // Ancho y alto: naturalWidth y naturalHeight
  // Para el tamaño hay que complicarse un poco más
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  
  var fileName = e.target.src.substring(e.target.src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  if (fileName.indexOf('?') >= 0){
    // Para quitar el querystring
    fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.indexOf('?'));
  }
  
  var width = e.target.naturalWidth;
  var height = e.target.naturalHeight;  
  
  fetch(e.target.src).then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    p.innerHTML = 'Nombre: ' + fileName 
      + '<br />Dimensiones: ' + width + 'px x ' 
      + height + 'px'
      + '<br />Tamaño: ' + parseInt(blob.size / 1024) + 'Kb';
  });
  content.appendChild(p);
  content.appendChild(e.target);
  // Cargar siguiente imagen
  cargarImagen();
}

cargarImagen();
```

```css
#content img{
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! es perfecto. Y el nombre del archivo como lo muestro también? por ejemplo que muestre 1.jpg si la imagen se llama así...

Comment: El nombre del archivo puedes obtenerlo de la ruta. He modificado el ejemplo para mostrarlo.